# Groovy - add missing method to Closure

Tags: groovy, mocking, closures

I am trying to mock `dockerImage.inside()` call
but I am getting following error. I tried just about anything, but am not able to add `inside()`:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.inside() is applicable for argument types: (String, com.dsl.shared.CustomService$_createMethod_closure15$_closure27) values: [-u root, com.dsl.shared.CustomService$_createMethod_closure15$_closure27@4248ed58]
Possible solutions: size(), size(), intern(), inspect(), find()
at com.dsl.shared.CustomService$_createMethod_closure15.doCall(CustomService.groovy:677)
```

BuildContentMock.groovy

```
class BuildContextMock {
    String commandCalled
    class dockerMock {
        def image(def imageName){
            return imageName
        }
    }

    dockerMock docker = new dockerMock()
    def sh(String command) {
        commandCalled = command
    }

    def usernamePassword(Map inputs) {
        inputs
    }

    def string(Map inputs) {
        inputs
    }

    def withCredentials(List args, Closure closure) {
        def delegate = [:]
        for (arg in args) {
            delegate[arg.get('usernameVariable')] = 'the_username'
            delegate[arg.get('passwordVariable')] = 'the_password'
            delegate[arg.get('variable')] = 'the_apikey'
        }
        closure.delegate = delegate
        closure()
    }
}
```

CustomServiceTest.groovy

```
class CustomServiceTest {
    @Test
    void testCreateMaintenanceWindow() {
        def buildContextMock = new BuildContextMock()
        def mockForBuildInfo = new MockFor(BuildInfo)
        def mockBuildInfo = mockForBuildInfo.proxyInstance()

        AEMBuildHelper aemBuildHelper = new AEMBuildHelper(buildContextMock, "artifactory", mockBuildInfo)
        CustomService customService = aemBuildHelper.customService      
        String id = customService.createMethod()
        assert id !== null
    }
}
```

CustomService.groovy

```
class CustomService extends BuildHelper {
    String createMaintenanceWindow(){            
       buildContext.withCredentials(
          [buildContext.string(credentialsId: 
              ApiKey, variable:'ApiKey')]){ 
           this.dockerBuildHelper.getDockerImage(       
               this.dockerBuildHelper.getWdBuildDockerImageName())
                  .inside('-u root'){       
               return sh(script: "test", returnStdout: true).trim()
           }
       }
    }
}
```

BuildHelper.groovy

```
 class BuildHelper extends ContextHolder implements Serializable {    
    protected def mavenBuildHelper = null    
    BuildHelper(buildContext, mavenBuildHelper) {
       super(buildContext)
       this.mavenBuildHelper = mavenBuildHelper
    }

    BuildHelper(buildContext, credentialId, buildContainerEntryPointCommand) {
       super(buildContext)
       this.mavenBuildHelper = new MavenBuildHelper(buildContext, credentialId, buildContainerEntryPointCommand)
    }
 }
```

DockerBuildHelper.groovy

```
class DockerBuildHelper extends BuildHelper {    
    DockerBuildHelper(buildContext, mavenBuildHelper, credentialsID = null) {
        super(buildContext, mavenBuildHelper)
        this.artifactoryCredentialsId = credentialsID
    }
    String getWdBuildDockerImageName() {
        return wdBuildDockerImageName
    }
    String getDockerImage(String imageName) {
        return buildContext.docker.image(imageName)
    }
}
```

Comment: according to your code `dockerBuildHelper.getDockerImage(..)` should return object that has a method `inside(...)` but it returns string.

Comment: @daggett yeap. mind boggling :)